# Show that any continuous map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow X$ is homotopic to the constant map

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

$\newcommand {\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
I want to show that any continuous map $f: \R^n \rightarrow X$ is homotopic to the constant map.

So far this is what I have:

My homotopy must look something like that:

$H(x,0) := f(x)$

$H(x,1) :=\gamma_0$

where $\gamma_0$ is in the same path connected component as the image of $\R^n$.

My question now is: could someone help me to formally write down the homotopy? Thanks!

**Edit:** *I took out my intuition for $H$ that I had described earlier as it was wrong and I do not wish to confuse future readers.*

Comment: The image of f is not necessary contractible. You should be able to describe a map R \to R^2 whose image is not contractible.

Comment: For the claim as you wrote it to be true you actually need to pick gamma0 in the same path connected component as the image of f...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks a lot. I see what you mean and changed my question accordingly

Comment: You edited the question and now what you wrote suggests an homotopy between f and the identity, but that does not make sense: f takes its argument in R^n while the identity is the identity of X. The x in the argument of H has to be an element of R^n, and the result of H has to be in X, so the equality H(x,1)=x does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(t, x) = f((1-t) x)$ should do the trick.

Comment: Gamma_0 is a point of X, @luna, so your observation does not make sense! You cannot sum points of X or multiply them by numbers.

Comment: Where did you want to write c(x)?

Comment: That does not make sense since, as I said, you cannot sum elements of X.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142460/discussion-between-luna-and-mariano-suarez-alvarez).